# provideIn: 'root' service replicated in library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a service exported from an angular library. The service is `providedIn: 'root'` and everything works fine on the consuming app side. However, the library appears to create another instance that is being injected into library components. (I basically have 2 instances of the service).

It's not registered in providers in any module, purely provided in root.

The library is arhitected with separate entry points for each service, so in the library components the service is imported as:
`import { Service } from '@organization/core/src/lib/services/service/service`. I read that the path also has influence on this.

I need to have the same instance in my library components as the consuming app.

EDIT: It seems to have something to do with paths:

Logging the constructor call I have 2 separte files that it occurs in.

For the library:

`organization-core-lib-services-service.js`

For the app:

`organization-core.js`.

The app uses `import { Service } from @organization/core`

Comment: First, restart your Angular local dev server if you haven't already.  If it's still showing up as a separate instance, your IDE probably added an import for that service into a module or component that you didn't notice.  Search though your codebase for that second import and remove it.  Unfortunately there's not enough information in your post to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: It appears to be something related to the import path.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the import path.

Singletons only work if they're imported from the same path.

I had `import { Service } from '@organization/core/src/lib/services/service` in my library and `import { Service } from '@organization/core'` in my application. The service was being instanciated twice because it was originating from 2 different source files.

I changed my app import to `import { Service} from '@organization/core/src/lib/services/service';` and it works as expected now.